# Unable to use Service as SingleTon object in Angular2 Final Release

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, singleton, angular2-services

The Service which I have and want to use throughout the application is

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailsService {
    objUser: User = new User();
    testing: string;
    getData() {
        return this.testing;        
    }
    setData(my:string) {
        debugger;
        this.testing = my;
    }
}
```

Now I want to set the variable testing in one of my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserDetailsService} from 'servicePath';

@Component({
    selector: 'some',
    templateUrl: 'someUrl',
    providers: [UserDetailsService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
constructor(private _Service: UserDetailsService)

}
onClick(){
_Service.set("my Value");
}
```

Now in another component if I want to use this field testing , I'm getting undefined

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {UserDetailsService} from 'URL';

@Component({
    selector: 'somee1',
    templateUrl: 'url'
})
export class LandingComponent {
    constructor(private _UserService: UserDetailsService) {
        debugger;
        var test = _UserService.getData();
        debugger;
    }
}
```

in my app module I have this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: ...,
    declarations:...,
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [HttpService, UserDetailsService]}]
})
```

Comment: I think that in order to use the service in multiple components you need a shared module.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `UserDetailsService` from `providers` of the component and keep it only in providers of `@NgModule()`

Angular2 DI maintains an instance per provider. If you provide it multiple times you get multiple instances. If you provide it at a component, you get an instance for any occurrence of that component in your application.

Providers added to `NgModule` are all added to the root scope and if a service is provided more than once, only a single instance is is added to the root scope.

**Lazy loaded modules** get their own scope, therefore this is a different case than the one explained before.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same :(

Comment: Sorry :-/, don't get discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

To create a shared module:

Create the shared module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ ErrorMessagesComponent ],
  exports: [ CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule, ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [ AuthorizationService, LoginService, AuthGuardService ]
    };
  }
}
```

In the app.module.ts (notice the sharedModule.forRoot()):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), SharedModule.forRoot(), 
               HomeModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ appRoutingProviders ]

})
```

then in every module that uses the shared module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ SharedModule, routing],
    declarations: [ HomeComponent], 
    bootstrap: [ HomeComponent ],
    providers: [ ]

})
```